# Why do the leaders of UK political parties need a seat in parliament?

Tags: united-kingdom, political-leaders

At the last election, UK centrist party the Liberal Democrats were reduced from around 50 to 8 MPs. After this catastrophe, their leader resigned, forcing a leadership contest. Two of the party's 8 remaining MPs stood, neither of whom was a well-known name in politics. Unsurprisingly, the winner has not revived the electoral fortunes of the party.

At the same election a couple of high-profile MPs for Labour, the left-wing party, also lost their seats. Chief among them was Ed Balls who had been tipped as a potential future leader. However, losing his seat seemed to disqualify him as a candidate in that party's leadership contest. Since he had the potential to unite the two wings of that party, his loss has potentially had a huge impact on their fortunes.

Both these event made me wonder why British parties consider it essential that their leader has a seat in Parliament. The role of leader would seem to be one of management, which does not directly require a vote in Parliament. Even if it did, it's merely a single vote which would rarely - if ever - matter a great deal in passing legislation.

Why don't British parties allow non-MPs to stand for party leadership positions?

Comment: As far as I can ascertain only the Liberal Democrats have an election procedure which *explicitly* states that leadership candidates have to be MPs. Having said that, the detailed rules for the Conservative Party seem to be almost impossible to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most **major** political parties don't do this because the leader of the largest political party traditionally becomes the [Prime Minister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Minister_of_the_United_Kingdom). It would be unfeasible for a party to put in place a Prime Minister who wasn't democratically elected and was rather elected by some technocrats or internal party mechanism. It is also unrealistic in a democracy for someone who hasn't been able to get themselves elected to a constituency to run the country.

However **minor** political parties often do. [Natalie Bennet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natalie_Bennett) was elected leader of the Green Party (*A party with only one sitting MP at the time of her election - [Caroline Lucas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caroline_Lucas)*) between 2012 - 2016 despite never being elected to any other political office. [Nigel Farage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigel_Farage) was leader of the UK Independence Party (*A party with no MP's at the time of his election*) between 2006 - 2016 and has never won a seat to parliament.

*Credit to [origimbo](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/7424/origimbo) for suggested edit regarding the number of MP's each party had at the time the leader became the leader*

Comment: It might be worth noting that Natalie Bennet was elected while the Green Party had only one sitting MP (current co-leader Caroline Lucas, who was then standing down as leader) while until 2014 UKIP had no MPs.

Comment: @origimbo updated with your suggestion

Comment: What is so 'inconvenient or impractical' about having a party leader who is not an MP? What makes it unrealistic? They might be standing in an opposition strong hold.

Comment: The same is also currently true for all of the smaller parties, most notably the SNP.

Comment: It would be entirely _legally_ possible for a non-MP leader to be PM. However, appointment of PM and invitation to form a government are matters in which the monarch still has discretion and it is very likely that the monarch would refuse, even if the non-MP leader were appointed to the Lords. (Alexander Douglas-Home sat in the Lords when appointed PM in 1963. A few days after being appointed PM, he renounced his earldom so he could be elected to a safe Tory seat in the Commons in a handy by-election; he was thus PM but a member of neither House of Parliament for the best part of a month.)

Comment: @tmgr Does the monarch REALLY have discretion, or is this one of those cases where they pretend she does on paper, but the backlash would likely end it/reverse it if she tried to use it that way?